# How to show a certain content type with Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

How can i create a page that lists nodes of a certain content type in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2):

Install the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views), create a new view and select a filter on the node type

Answer (score 1):

The views module will help you achieve this.